# copying files in tcl

Tags: tcl, file-copying

I have a query in "file copy" tcl command. I tried storing all my files to a list and used it in my command. But tcl is not recognizing those files.

for example:

```
    Files are abc.log , foo.log , bar.log
```

if these files are appended to a list say list_file and If I substitute the list_file in my command

```
    lappend list_file abc.log foo.log bar.log
    file mkdir ../../abc
    file copy -- $list_file ../../abc
```

I am getting  an error message " error copying , no file or directory". If I try the same by directly specifying the file names (instead of list) it works. Please guide me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on @evil-otto's answer...

`{*}` is only available since Tcl 8.5; for earlier versions either `eval` or multiple invocations could be used.

Constructing a command using `eval`:

```
set cmd [list file copy --]
lappend cmd abc.log foo.log bar.log ../../abc
eval $cmd
```

(Read [this](http://beedub.com/book/3rd/Eval.pdf) to learn why using lists is a must when creating commands to be `eval`uated.)

Multiple invocation (a no-brainer):

```
foreach fname $list_file {
    file copy -- $fname ../../abc
}
```

Comment: thanks! how to copy a directory? it says "can't overwrite file"

Answer (score 1):

The list passed to `file copy` must be expanded.

```
file copy -- {*}$list_file ../../abc
```